# C#: Access different property in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have this scenario:

```
private MyResponse MakeTransaction<T>(T data)
{
    TransactionData transactionData = new TransactionData()
    {
        number = data.Number
    }

    if(req is NewPayoutData) {
        transactionData.New = data.New;
    }
    ....
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
public MyResponse Payment(PayoutData data)
{
    return MakeTransaction(data);
}

public MyResponse NewPayment(NewPayoutData data)
{
    return MakeTransaction(data);
}
```

The problem is that 'Number' property exists in both types but the 'New' property exists only in 'NewPayment' Type.
How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do they share the same base class / interface? If so, you can constrain the generic type.

Comment: It sounds like *maybe* you shouldn't be using generics for this, and just overloading. In your example, is `req` meant to be `data`?

Answer (score 1):

The best you're going to get with generics is to constrain `T` to be a common interface or base class that has the `Number` property. However this leaves out the setting of the `New` property which is still based on type checking. Assuming an interface it might look like:

```
public interface IPayout
{
     int Number { get; }
}
public class PayoutData : IPayout { ... }
public class NewPayoutData : IPayout { ... }

private MyResponse MakeTransaction<T>(T data) where T: IPayout
{ 
     TransactionData transactionData = new TransactionData
     { 
         number = data.Number // now works 
     };

     // type checking still required :-(
     if(data is NewPayoutData) 
     { 
        transactionData.New = true; 
     }
     ... 
}
```

The type checking sort of defeats the purpose of generics. If you only have the two types a generic method is probably not the best way to go. I'd consider method *overloading* instead--especially since `NewPayoutData` looks to just be a *marker type*:

```
private MyResponse MakeTransaction(PayoutData data)
{ 
     TransactionData transactionData = new TransactionData
     { 
         number = data.Number
     };
     ... 
}

private MyResponse MakeTransaction(NewPayoutData data)
{ 
     TransactionData transactionData = new TransactionData 
     { 
         number = data.Number, 
         New = true
     };
     ... 
}
```

If they have an inheritence relationship, you *could* still have a single method that checks for the subclass:

```
public class PayoutData
{ 
     public int Number { get; set; } 
}

public class NewPayoutData : PayoutData
{ 
}

private MyResponse MakeTransaction(PayoutData data)
{ 
     TransactionData transactionData = new TransactionData
     { 
         number = data.Number
     };

     // type checking 
     if(data is NewPayoutData) 
     { 
        transactionData.New = true; 
     }
     ... 
}
```

My preferred method would be overloading as I think it's more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You could specifically cast transactionData to the required type. Better would probably be to make helper methods that deal with (strongly typed) functionality and call those from MakeTransaction.

I'm not entirely sure of your inheritance model, nor what you actually return in MakeTransaction, so I could be off base.